# Positioning text within an irregular area

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice-writer

I am trying to write a greeting card using a background with graphics in the upper-right and bottom-left corners. Something like this:

[image]

Using Word, I want the text to shape itself to be within the white area, so it will end up something like this:

```
  First line
    Second line
      Third line
```

etc.

How can I do this?

I have Microsoft Word 2010, but LibreOffice Writer is also an option.

Comment: @Akina Perhaps post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw triangle(s). Then Format AutoShape - Wrapping style - Tight.

[image]